# Что я делаю не так, нужно, каждое число в массиве умножить на 2

Tags: javascript

```js
    let arr = [17, 23, 31, 44, 59];
    
    doubleNumber(arr); // вернутся должно вот это [34,46,62,88,118];
    
    function doubleNumber(array) {
       let doubles = arr.map(function(num) {
           return num * 2;
    });
      console.log(doubles);
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вы передавали `array`, а мапу делали по `arr`

```js
let arr = [17, 23, 31, 44, 59];

doubleNumber(arr);

function doubleNumber(array) {
    let doubles = array.map(function(num) {
       return num * 2;
    });
    console.log(doubles);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы что-то "вернулось", надо из функции что-то вернуть.

```js
let arr = [17, 23, 31, 44, 59];

let doubles = doubleNumber(arr); // вернуться должно вот это [34,46,62,88,118];
console.log(doubles);

function doubleNumber(array) {
  return array.map(function(num) {
    return num * 2;
  });
}
```

Comment: Не понимаю причины создание функции которая будет возвращать массив, если map и так это делает

Answer (score 1):

Не стоит создавать целую функцию для умножения каждого элемента массива на 2, это портит Ваш код. метод `map` и так возвращает новый массив.

Ваш код должен выглядеть так

```js
let arr = [17, 23, 31, 44, 59]

console.log("Arr: ", arr);

arr = arr.map((el)=>el*2);

console.log("new Arr: ", arr);

// Or

const arr1 = [17, 23, 31, 44, 59]

console.log("Arr: ", arr1);

const newArr = arr1.map((el)=>el*2);

console.log("new Arr: ", newArr);
```